# How to setup a git structure where a submodule requires an external library underneath it?

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I'm using git and my project (MyProject) has added as a submodule a public git project hosted on github (SubProject) underneath its directory structure. SubProject requires a library (SomeLibrary) to be contained underneath its directory structure.

Now that sucks, because if it wasn't for SubProject requiring SomeLibrary to be underneath it, this would be very simple. Because I've already added SubProject as a submodule of MyProject, there'd be nothing more to do. However, SomeLibrary is required and it isn't hosted in any git repository. So I'll create a new repository and tag it with its version number. But what's the best way of tying it all together?

Once SomeLibrary is in a git repository that I create for it, can I add SomeLibrary as a submodule underneath MyProject, or must it be a submodule of SubProject? If it's a submodule of SubProject, what's the best way to do it knowing that I may need to upgrade SubProject from new tagged releases over time? An example workflow would really help me wrap my head around this, because I'm having trouble conceptualizing what it would look like. (e.g. Would I branch SubProject before doing anything, or is that not necessary, meaning I could just extract SomeLibrary underneath SubProject and commit...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some kind of build system (make, maven, ant, MSBuild, etc.), perhaps you can circumvent the entire problem by placing the library somewhere in the parent git repository and making the build system copy the library to the submodule when building.

Otherwise, you might have to create a branch in the submodule, add the library and commit, and then commit the submodule change in the parent repository. Whenever the submodule author produces an update, you must pull it into your branch (thus giving you the update while retaining the library) and commit in the parent repository. However, if you want to clone the parent git repository on other computers and get the correct submodule contents, you must push this submodule branch to some location that you control (for example, your own github fork of the project). Hence, the submodule will need to remotes: the original github project (for pulling updates from the author) and your github fork (for pushing the merges of the author's updates with your library branch).

Comment: Not using build systems. So in your first option, what's the purpose of branching - couldn't I just make these commits in the main branch and still go along pulling in updates from the public repo? In your second option, could you describe what you mean by my own fork of the project? I should've described that my local repository will connect to our shared but internal repository. So could my submodule have only 1 remote which is that shared repo - I'd push to it, and the submodule in the shared repo would have 1 remote which is the public repo and would pull from it...would this work?

Comment: @user779159: Sure, you could stay on the main branch; it just feels more correct (in my opinion) to create a new branch because you are not actually intending to eventually merge your changes into the open-source repository you cloned. The approach you are describing with having only the internal repository as a remote locally and having github as a remote for the internal repository should work.